# nix installation issue on Fedora 35

Tags: nix, nix-shell

I just ran `sh <(curl -L https://nixos.org/nix/install) --daemon`  to install nix via its installation instructions. I proceeded through the installation menu where it backs up your bashrc and other config files. `y` on sudo permissions, it installs and doesn't complain.

`systemctl status systemctl status nix-daemon.service`
daemon running with no issues. However when I execute `nix-shell` I get

```
nix-shell: /nix/store/jsp3h3wpzc842j0rz61m5ly71ak6qgdn-glibc-2.32-54/lib/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/libsodium.so.23)
```

When I execute `nix-env --version` same error.

I've uninstalled / reinstalled nix several times now and getting the same error. Checked Fedora 35 glibc version  `ldd --version` and get back 2.34

Any advice on getting nix-shell to execute properly in Fedora 35?

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Comment: Where id you run `nix-shell`, in which folder?

Answer (score 3):

Fixed. I had the Cardano node previously installed which involves compiling and installing libsodium. What I did was go into the libsodium folder and `sudo make libsodium uninstall` Then re-ran nix installation and now I get a nix-shell.

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Comment: For me the `make` command failed and I had to go to `/usr/local/lib`, created a backup directory and moved all `libsodium.*` files to it. This removed that existing lib and nix installed fine.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and got ahold of a fedora 35 install. I was *not* able to install the `--daemon` version, due to [fedoras SELinux enforcement](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/2374). I did however manage to install `nix` in single user mode.

and nix-shell works.

```
$ nix-shell -p hello
these 42 paths will be fetched (61.29 MiB download, 281.92 MiB unpacked):
...
[nix-shell:~]$ hello
Hello, world!

[nix-shell:~]$
```

Comment: Sadly I'm getting the same error with single user mode installation.

`sh <(curl -L https://nixos.org/nix/install) --no-daemon`
copying Nix to /nix/store...........................................
/nix/store/azld8vfyqb4fx6bxdz28n3nw23nghf88-nix-2.5.1/bin/nix-store: /nix/store/jsp3h3wpzc842j0rz61m5ly71ak6qgdn-glibc-2.32-54/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/libsodium.so.23)
/tmp/nix-binary-tarball-unpack.PWdwdaEWRp/unpack/nix-2.5.1-x86_64-linux/install: unable to register valid paths

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I noticed it happens when you had/have previously setup a Cardano node since that required setting up libsodium. The issue is with the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` envronment variable added in the process.

To solve it I commented out that variable export in the `~/.bashrc` file. You may need to restart the terminal for the change to take effect.