# GLIBC_2.33 Not Found After Installing Cardano Node .?

Tags: nix-shell

`nix-shell: /nix/store/jsp3h3wpzc842j0rz61m5ly71ak6qgdn-glibc-2.32-54/lib/libc.so.6: version` GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/libsodium.so.23)`

My nix-Shell was working fine but after i install cardano node i start giving me this error.

Comment: Which system is this on? Potential duplicate of https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/6405/nix-installation-issue-on-fedora-35.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nix installation issue on Fedora 35](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/6405/nix-installation-issue-on-fedora-35)